# Interpolating Text with SFSymbol in Swiftui

Tags: string, image, swiftui, interpolation, sf-symbols

I would like to interpolate a text with a pallete colored SFSymbol in swiftui. Is there a way I can do this?

Currently I receive an error: `'appendInterpolation' is unavailable: Unsupported type for interpolation, see LocalizedStringKey.StringInterpolation for supported types.`

Thus, I am not sure is possible yet.
I know that is possible with no properties like: `Text("Hello \(Image(systemName: "person.3.sequence.fill"))")`

What I am trying to achieve:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    var aux = Image(systemName: "person.3.sequence.fill")
                  .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
                  .foregroundStyle(.red, .green, .blue)
    return Text("Hello \(aux)")
}
```

}